# Call method GetStoredProcCommand but get a procedure unexpected

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, enterprise-library

I am using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary v2.0.50727.
When I use the method "GetStoredProcCommand" to get a command object by procedure name, such as A, but it have a small chance to execute another procedure, such as B.
This is my database class.

```
public class DatabaseBase
{
    private string _connString = "ConnectionString";
    private DbCommand _commandObject;

    protected string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return _connString; }
        set { _connString = value; }
    }

    protected Database DatabaseObject
    {
        get { return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(_connString); }
    }

    protected DbCommand CommandObject
    {
        get { return _commandObject; }
        set { _commandObject = value; }
    }

    public DatabaseBase()
    {
    }

    protected void SetCommandObjectProcedure(string procedure)
    {
        CommandObject = DatabaseObject.GetStoredProcCommand(procedure);
        CommandObject.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    public void MethodA(int a)
    {
        SetCommandObjectProcedure("A");
        DatabaseObject.AddInParameter(CommandObject, "a1", DbType.Int32, a);
        DatabaseObject.ExecuteReader(CommandObject);
    }

    public IDataReader MethodB(int b1,int b2)
    {
        SetCommandObjectProcedure("B");
        DatabaseObject.AddInParameter(CommandObject, "b1", DbType.Int32, b1);
        DatabaseObject.AddInParameter(CommandObject, "b2", DbType.Int32, b2);
        return DatabaseObject.ExecuteReader(CommandObject);
    }
}
```

When I call the MethodA for thousands times in a  loop

```
        foreach (inta in listA)
        {
            Database.MethodA(int a);
        }
```

I will have a small chance to get an exception like this:

```
Procedure or function B has too many arguments specified.
at Database.MethodA(int a)
```

.......miracle!
There is no multi-threading.
How could procedure B be in Method A?
Could some one help me finger out what happen?

Modify Method A like this:

```
   public void MethodA(int a)
    {
        using(var command = DatabaseObject.GetStoredProcCommand("A"))
        {
          DatabaseObject.AddInParameter(command , "a1", DbType.Int32, a);
          DatabaseObject.ExecuteReader(command );
        }
    }
```

Now the command is disposed. But issue still exists.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you're calling `MethodA for thousands times in a loop`

Comment: I have post the loop code, it is very sample.

Comment: Whatever the cause of the issue is, the correct fix is almost certainly to stop keeping a long-lived `Command` object around and re-using it. The only long-lived/shared item you should have around data access is the connection *string*. The other objects (`Connection`, `Command`, `Reader`) should be created, used and then disposed of, preferably inside of `using` statements and all cleaned up by the end of the method that uses them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbelieve, even I use a local variable to save the command and use `using` to dispose it, this issue still exists. See the MethodA.